# How to stop time synchronization on an Azure VM

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, time

I'm trying to simulate a different date/time on an Azure VM but the time keeps resetting itself to the current date/time.  Is there a way to force the server to stay at a specific date/time until I manually change it back?

I have disabled the Windows Time service, the Hyper-V Time Synchronization Service and changed the time settings to not synchronize with an internet time server.  Before doing this the server would immediately revert to the correct date/time, but now it will stay for an hour or more and then revert.

With those items out of the picture, what causes this and is there a way to stop it?

Answer (score 9):

I got this to work for a VM running Windows 2008 on Azure (converted from a physical server). My settings are as follows:

- Hyper-V Time Synchronization Service, startup set to "Manual"
- Windows Time Service, startup set to "Manual"
- Time settings set to actively synchronize with "time.windows.com" (I care about the date being different, not the time)

Comment: Thanks, turning off Hyper-V Time Sync Service did the trick for me! I was getting worried for a while